# Java process failure (hadoop, hbase)

Tags: hadoop, java, hbase

Anytime I am running hadoop/hbase process from a command prompt I get an error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: Success
```

I get the same kind of error when I start hbase.

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Could you please tell me what could cause the issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an incompatibility with your java version.

Try to follow http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions recommendations and get the right java versions installed.